# Cookie Domain is preventing Admin login

Tags: wp-admin, login, wp-config, cookies

I just defined a Cookie Domain in my `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN',  'http://www.example.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME',        'http://www.example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL',     'http://www.example.com/wp' );
```

I thought it was working until I tried logging into the Wordpress admin `http://www.example.com/wp/wp-admin` and got this:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you need to set cookie domain? Have you tried without `http://`? PHP's `setcookie` domain should not contain `http://`.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the protocol worked! If you want to answer the question with that response I'll accept it. Also, setting up a "Cookie Domain" allows content from other domains to be served cookie-free (i.e. smaller file size)